# call plugin properties on double-click

Tags: dialog, ckeditor

I am using CKEditor 3.6.4

By the default CKEditor calls dialog properties on double click, but on the CKEditor I am working is not calling the dialog properties. What could be some possible reasons?

Comment: Providing sample links for your test pages would improve your chances of getting a good answer fast

Answer (score 0):

double click properties are defined in the plugin.js file

```
editor.on( 'doubleclick', function( evt )
        {
            var element = evt.data.element;

            if ( element.is( 'typeOfElement' ) )
                evt.data.dialog = 'commandName';

        });
},
```